# InnoSetup: dll can't be deleted at uninstall

Tags: file, installation, inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

I'm using the VCL Styles provided in this link to skin my installer/uninstaller: https://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-plugins/wiki/VCLStylesInnoSetup

But when I uninstall the program, the dll that contains the functions is not deleted.

How I can delete it?.

I've thinked about this alternative: Copy the dll to a temporary folder and load that temporary dll that Windows Cleaner should delete in the future, but that causes me another problem that I talk about that in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863987/innosetup-pascalscript-filecopy-doesnt-copy
But that's another problem, what I would like to know here is how I can delete this dll file.

This is the full `[Code]` section that I'm using, notice the `DeinitializeUninstall` method where I try to delete the file:

```
// Import the LoadVCLStyle function from VclStylesInno.DLL
procedure LoadVCLStyle(VClStyleFile: String); external 'LoadVCLStyleA@files:unins000.dll stdcall setuponly';
procedure LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(VClStyleFile: String); external 'LoadVCLStyleA@{app}\unins000.dll stdcall uninstallonly';

// Import the UnLoadVCLStyles function from VclStylesInno.DLL
procedure UnLoadVCLStyles; external 'UnLoadVCLStyles@files:unins000.dll stdcall setuponly';
procedure UnLoadVCLStyles_UnInstall; external 'UnLoadVCLStyles@{app}\unins000.dll stdcall uninstallonly';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
    ExtractTemporaryFile('unins000.vsf');
    LoadVCLStyle(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\unins000.vsf'));
    Result := True;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
    UnLoadVCLStyles;
end;

function InitializeUninstall: Boolean;
begin
    Result := True;
    LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(ExpandConstant('{app}\unins000.vsf'));
end;

procedure DeinitializeUninstall();
begin
    UnLoadVCLStyles_UnInstall;
    DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\unins000.dll'));
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unload the library before deleting. Use the [`UnloadDLL`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_unloaddll) function for that (the help contains an example just for this case). Missing that leads the `DeleteFile` function to fail in your code. For your uninstaller write this instead:

```
procedure LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(VClStyleFile: String); external 'LoadVCLStyleA@{app}\unins000.dll stdcall uninstallonly';
procedure UnLoadVCLStyles_UnInstall; external 'UnLoadVCLStyles@{app}\unins000.dll stdcall uninstallonly';

function InitializeUninstall: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(ExpandConstant('{app}\unins000.vsf'));
end;

procedure DeinitializeUninstall();
begin
  UnLoadVCLStyles_UnInstall;
  UnloadDLL(ExpandConstant('{app}\unins000.dll'));
  DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\unins000.dll'));
end;
```